# flash disappear after few seconds in ie6

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, flash, swfobject

My flash is working fine in all browser except ie6. **During loading of page I see flash fine in ie6 but once page is loaded flash disappears**. Looked everywhere but can not find solution.

in ie6 downloaded latest player WIN 10,3,181,34. version detected at http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/155/tn_15507.html

javascript file has

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    swfobject.registerObject("mymovie", "9.0.0", "expressInstall.swf");
});
```

Below is code in helper in app_code folder

```
@helper SwfObject(string swfName, UrlHelper url)    {
    <object id="mymovie" classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000" width="960" height="315" style="background-color: #e6e6e6;" wmode="transparent">
        <param name="movie" value="@url.Content("../../Content/flash/" + swfName)"  />
        <param name="wmode" value="opaque" />
        <object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="@url.Content("../../Content/flash/" + swfName)" width="960" height="315" style="background-color: #e6e6e6;" wmode="transparent">
            <div>
                <img src="@url.Content("../../Content/gallery/album1/large/1.png")" alt="Image"/>
                <p><a href="http://www.adobe.com/go/getflashplayer"><img src="http://www.adobe.com/images/shared/download_buttons/get_flash_player.gif" alt="Get Adobe Flash player" /></a></p>
            </div>
        </object>
    </object>
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`swfobject.registerObject` shouldn't be wrapped in a `$(document).ready` function or any similar onload functions, such as `window.onload`.

- [Demo](http://demos.learnswfobject.com/basics/static-with-javascript.html)
- [Tutorial](http://learnswfobject.com/the-basics/using-javascript-with-static-publishing/)
- The [official example](http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/wiki/documentation#STEP_3%3a_Register_your_Flash_content_with_the_SWFObject_library_a) in the SWFObject documentation